# Is a 100 euro bill common and perceived as normal?

Tags: europe, money

I think 100 dollar bills are common both in US and outside but not sure about euro. Seems like no?

Asking because apparently having a 500 euro bill makes you look shady and cause hassle according to reports of some people which I find weird.

Comment: I think I've had a $100 bill in my hand/wallet once or twice in my life. They really are not commonly used in the US in ordinary transactions.

Comment: €500 were discontinued for basically being only used by organised crime, hence the association. €100 don't have the same link, but high-value notes are always treated somewhat skeptically because they are attractive to counterfitters.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146079/discussion-on-question-by-oooooo-is-a-100-euro-bill-common-and-perceived-as-norm); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: Not in the Eurozone, but worth noting that the 100 Swiss Franc note, which is of similar value, is common.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Between uncommon and barely usable, depending on the country:**

[netherlands](/questions/tagged/netherlands)

A €100 banknote is barely usable in ordinary supermarkets. Some will refuse to accept one altogether, in others you will see the cashier call a couple more colleagues to inspect your banknote before ultimately accepting it. (€200 and €500 banknotes are basically not accepted anywhere.)

[france](/questions/tagged/france)

Similarly to the Netherlands, bills of 100€ or above are uncommon, but some ATMs still deliver them. 200€ bills especially are so rare that a lot of French don't even know they exist at all, and most have never seen one.
Bigger stores like supermarkets will check those bills more thoroughly but tend to accept them widely.
A lot of smaller stores do try to refuse the bills and put up disclaimers. However, as long as you provide exact change it is illegal for a shopkeeper to refuse cash as payment ([article R642-3](https://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/codes/article_lc/LEGIARTI000022375969) of the Penal Code), unless one tries to pay with more than 50 coins.

In the same vein, it is also illegal and considered discrimination for most sellers to refuse serving a paying customer  ([article R132-1](https://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/codes/article_lc/LEGIARTI000032807172) of the Consumer Protection Code and [article 225-2](https://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/codes/article_lc/LEGIARTI000033975382) of the Penal Code) outside of very specific reasons.
Notable exclusions to these laws include some services such as banking and insurance, as well as commerce between private companies.

Comment: I'm not too much of a cash person so I don't have much experience with large denominations across EU member states. Others will hopefully add their experience to this community wiki post.

Comment: I think one concern in France is the amount of change in your checkout. I assume paying a good restaurant meal with €100 could raise eyebrows but would ultimately be OK. Breaking it to pay for a €5 receipt, not so much.

Comment: common in Germany, though, even for paying small amounts.

Comment: Is it even legal _not_ to accept valid cash payment?

Comment: @Zeus in the US, absolutely.  while this is often limited to bills > a certain value, there are  no-cash businesses popping up in increasing numbers (though some states/cities prohibit this). in Europe it seems harder to completely refuse acceptance of any value note (run a credit/debit only business), but refusal of higher value notes are common

Comment: @Zeus it is legal for a private business to refuse your business for no reason, so consequently, they can just refuse your cash by refusing your business. You're probably thinking of a federally backed institution like a bank.

Comment: @Nelson In France, is is illegal for a company to refuse dealing with someone, (except for the banks, strangely...)

Comment: @njzk2 I wouldn't call them common but they do appear and are accepted in most stores. A 50 Euro note will be accepted essentially everywhere for any amount. A 100 Euro note will be ok for a decent sized purchase in most places. If you try to pay for 2 scoops of icecream the seller will definitely be annoyed at a 100 Euro bill.

Comment: This is false: I have paid my shopping with 100/200€ bills in large supermarkets with no problems. They do check the bill more thoroughly, but that hardly makes it "barely usable". Small shops often only accept 50€ bills and smaller.

Comment: @Zeus If the note is a legal tender in the country, it cannot be refused as a payment for debt. A restaurant check might be considered such a debt, but a supermarket check certainly not.

Comment: @Zeus I don't know the situation in Netherlands or France, but in the UK (not just England & Wales) and US, cash cannot be refused _as payment of a debt_, but businesses can refuse to do business with you for any reason not otherwise prohibited. This means a restaurant where you get your food then pay after the fact can't refuse legal tender, but a bar where you pay before getting your drink can. Some coins also stop being legal tender above a certain number

Comment: Your drug dealer will probably take them though...

Comment: @Tristan I am not sure, but I think that only the cash issued  by the Bank of England, not by the Bank of Scotland, Royal Bank of Scotland  or the Northern Ireland ones.

Comment: The description for France is very precise and correct. If you have a bill of 520€, you can pay 2x200+100+20 and nobody can refuse it (if they refuse, you could arguably build a case where you do not need to pay. Two wrongs do not make it a right, but at least there is some ground). You could also pay 500+20, which would be highly unusual but, again, absolutely legal and the vendor has to accept.  Now - a vendor can refuse a note that is "obviously" false, but has to accept one if they have doubts (they can take note of your identity). If they refused I would call the police, though.

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава - Technically, that's not even quite right, only Bank of England coinage is "legal tender", not even their paper notes. In practice though, a court will laugh at anyone who refuses to accept a paper cash settlement of debt. The legal definition of "legal tender" is archaic and needs updating

Comment: In the Netherlands most businesses try to avoid 100 Euro and 200 Euro bills because of the high percentage of counterfeit ones, and the trouble breaking them for change as many stores carry very little cash for that. That said, many will accept them for large transactions but put a strict limit on the change they hand you. So if you pay 124 Euro with 100+20+5 you'll get 1 Euro back, don't expect to get 76 Euro back if you pay with a 200 Euro note.

Answer (score 21):

[germany](/questions/tagged/germany)

Germany is still strong on using cash, both for small day-to-day purchases and large ones (cars or until recently [even houses](https://www.sueddeutsche.de/wirtschaft/immobilienkauf-kein-bargeld-mehr-1.5681975)). The latter is seen as a serious money laundering concern, but reform is stuck in debate.

Using the €50 note is quite common, but it may lead to grumbling from shopkeepers when it is used for small purchases. *"Haben Sie es nicht kleiner?" "Don't you have it smaller?"*

Using the €100 and €200 note is less common but not unheard, and my perception is that it isn't seen as shady. Just unusual, most people who spend that kind of money use digital payment systems.

There are shops which have posted notice that they are refusing the €500 note out of forgery concerns. The occasional forged, undetected 50 is the cost of doing business, a forged 500 would seriously impact their earnings.

Comment: The ATM I usually use here where I live in Germany always gives me 100€ notes if I withdraw more than 100€. I have never had any problem actually using them. I often exchange cash when I am in eastern Europe and have also there never had problems using 100€ notes.

Comment: In US shops, it's quite common to see signs saying "no bills over $20 accepted".

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo, I very rarely encountered problems (first customer in the morning for a small shop ...) and frequently grumpiness.

Comment: Same as @Tor-EinarJarnbjo (also in Germany), my ATM always gives me some 100s, and they're generally not a problem. My baker has a sign up that they don't take 100s and 200s, but their transactions go rarely above 10€, and the one time I shopped there and had nothing but a 100 they took it without issue - of course, I shop there almost every day, so they know me, and probably decided forged money wouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Non-supermarket stores (bakeries, newspapers etc.) may not accept them even without an explicit note. Supermarkets usually do though. The legal side is somewhat interesting: It is legal tender, so is there not an *obligation* to accept it? There is; but there is no obligation to make change. So if you buy something for 101 Euros and pay with a bill and a coin, everybody should accept that (they still sometimes won't though).

Comment: Buying a house with cash has become [**illegal**](https://www.haufe.de/immobilien/wirtschaft-politik/geldwaesche-was-immobilienunternehmen-beachten-muessen_84342_523282.html) in Germany since 2023-04-01.

Comment: @RonJohn likewise in the UK, where £50 notes are our highest denomination they're often not accepted (and pretty universally treated with extra scrutiny even when they are accepted)

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica is that the case in Germany? In the UK & US legal tender means it must be accepted _as payment for a debt_, but a business can decline to do business with you for any reason not otherwise prohibited. This essentially means it must be accepted as payment for goods & services rendered in advance of payment (e.g. at most restaurants), but if you pay first (like in a supermarket or bar) they can refuse it

Comment: @Tristan Probably [not only in Germany](https://www.ecb.europa.eu/euro/cash_strategy/html/cash-faq.en.html): "-Retailers cannot refuse cash payments unless both parties have agreed to use a different means of payment. -Displaying a label or posters indicating that the retailer refuses payments in cash, or payments made in certain banknote denominations, is not enough. The retailer must provide a legitimate excuse, such as a difficulty maintaining sufficient cash reserves to provide change or concrete physical security risks due to the presence of large amounts of cash. "

Comment: @Tristan The reason is clear enough: The only value of paper money is the trust that you can buy stuff with it (at least after the end of the gold guarantee).

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica Tristan is right here. Your quote 'cannot refuse ...' is from an EU recommendation and not any legally binding regulation. Unless he breaks other laws (e.g. against discrimination), no German retailer is obligated to do business with you for whatever other reason he finds suitable.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo Well, from the quoted paper: "there is currently some legal uncertainty at the euro area level with regards to a common interpretation and definition of legal tender". The experts of the Euro Legal Tender Expert Group are of the quoted opinion, you are of a different opinion. Are you aware of a court decision supporting yours? (I'm not being sarcastic.)

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica Once again: What you are quoting is a recommendation and not a legal opinion or a binding regulation. That is not my opinion, but a clear fact if you read the entirety of what you are linking to and not just pick out a fragment. There is in Germany AFAIK no court decision supporting my opinion, simply because the legal situation is so crystal clear, that noone has challenged a shop's rejection of cash payment in court. The assessment of the Federal Criminal Police Office agrees with me: https://www.bka.de/SharedDocs/FAQs/DE/Falschgeld/falschgeldFrage01.html

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo (1) I'm not sure how you can say "the legal situation is so crystal clear" if the assembled experts on the matter write "there is currently some legal uncertainty". (2) "jeder Zahlungsempfänger [ist] dazu verpflichtet, Euro-Banknoten als ordnungsgemäße Erfüllung einer monetären Verbindlichkeit zu akzeptieren (sog. Annahme-zwang)." (https://www.bundestag.de/resource/blob/811390/50314e855ea6baba97204e02ad4d4d01/WD-4-117-20-pdf-data.pdf)

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica Because your talk about 'legal tender' is mostly irrelevant for the issue we are discussing. You are completely right that cash payments must be accepted if they are offered as payment for a debt (monetäre Verbindlichkeit), that is the meaning of 'legal tender', but if a retailer refuses to do business with you, there is no debt to be paid and irrelevant what kind of payment must be accepted for the non-existing debt.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica You are also once again just quoting small fragments of the material you are linking to. To bring out the relevant part of the last document you misinterpret: 'diie Pflicht zur Annahme von Bargeld in Deutschland [kann] durch eine privatrechtliche Vereinbarung ausgeschlossen werden' - 'the duty to accept cash payments in Germany can be ruled out by an agreement based on civil law'.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo Which part of "Annahmezwang" is it that you don't understand? ;-) As you may know, a contract in German private law requires mutual consent; if I insist in cash, that consent does not exist, hence no private contract to forfeit my right to pay in cash exists, hence *Annahmezwang* persists. I thought that's not relevant (most rights outside the *Grundrechte* can be forfeited contractually, so that's common but does not invalidate the respective right).

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica You are still picking out minor fragments of what you are quoting and obviously do not even try to understand what I am explaining. Of course I know what 'Annahmezwang' means and I have already in my last comment explained why it is irrelevant, because the situation, in which the obligation to accept is described, does not exist. And you are perfectly right, a contract in Germany requires mutual consent and that is exactly the reason why a retailer is not obligated to sell you something if you do not agree to the payment conditions given by the seller.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica If you insist in paying cash for a purchase and the retailer wants card payment, you are furthermore correct that there is no consent about the contract agreements, which against means that no purchase has been made (the sale is part of the contract you refuse to enter), you have no monetary debt to the retailer, the retailer does not owe you any merchandise and there is no situation, in which the meaning of 'legal tender' could have been relevant,

Comment: I would also note that 100 euro notes are likely to become more and more common due to very high inflation rates, unless we see a full transition to cashless societies. A few more years of 7-8% inflation (not unreasonable due to the war spending) and 100 euros will seem like a relatively small amount.

Comment: @gerrit Netherlands I think outlawed any cash transaction over a few thousand Euros, maybe that's EU wide even.

Answer (score 17):

In Austria, definitely yes. 100 euro bills come out of ATMs, so many people regularly have some of them and spend them.

200 and 500 euro bills, not so much.

Comment: Same with Germany. The only places which don't accept it are places where the average purchase is in the 1€–30€ range and that are small independent businesses for which keeping large amounts of change at hand would tie up a considerable amount of their money. For example, the bakery in my street displays prominent signs saying they don't take denominations larger than 50€. OTOH, when I was working as a musician, it was almost a cliché that at every wedding, the father of the bride would pay us in 500€ notes.

Comment: Apparently, it is completely normal that the father of the bride gets a large envelope of 500€ notes from the bank and pays the band, the DJ, the catering company, the flower company, the venue, etc. that way. At least that is what I observed at every wedding I ever played at. (And it was always an annoyance, because you then had to break 500€ notes between the band members or employees.)

Comment: Was just gonna comment on this. Absolutely agree

Comment: @JörgWMittag I'd be suspicious if that still happens: no €500 notes have been printed since 2015, so they are unlikely to be still in normal circulation through banks.

Comment: I’m Austrian. I would have agreed with your statement but recently I had trouble paying for a 8€ sandwich at Subway with a 50€ note at 11:20 because they simply didn’t have enough cash in the register. The nearby pizza store was also unable to exchange it for some smaller notes. Kind of ridiculous (and everyone I’ve told this agreed).

Comment: In my experience, Austrian ATMs _frequently_ dispense €200 notes, much to my chagrin, since many shops won't accept them (either as a matter of policy or because they don't stock enough change). For this reason I avoid withdrawing more than €190 at a time, or else use ATMs that I already know allow the user to select the denomination of bills.

Comment: @Psychonaut This is not my experience at all. I spend most of my time in Vienna and am very certain I have never gotten a 200 euro bill from an ATM.

Answer (score 10):

Anything above €50 is extremely uncommon outside of a handful of cash-friendly countries (mostly Austria and Germany, which are [the only countries to have produced any in recent years](https://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/policy_and_exchange_rates/banknotes+coins/production/html/index.en.html)). Business owners might not be happy to break a €50 but that's hard to avoid when that's what some ATM give you. Some will have signs explicitly warning that they won't accept €100, €200, or €500 banknotes.

Beyond that, many countries in the eurozone have also moved away from cash generally, which also means businesses have less change on hand when they are not outright refusing cash. There are also limits on how much you are allowed to pay by cash in [about half of all eurozone countries](https://www.europe-consommateurs.eu/en/shopping-internet/cash-payment-limitations.html) further contributing to a general lack of use for large denominations.

Answer (score 6):

One possible reason for hassle with a €500 note, that should be rather independent of spending habits in a certain country: as of 2019, €500 notes are no longer being issued ([source](https://www.ecb.europa.eu/euro/banknotes/html/index.en.html#500)). The reason, as others have mentioned, was that €500 notes were often used in criminal activities.

I admit that I misunderstood those news, thinking that the €500 notes are no longer legal tender, and it's likely that the same happened some shopowners or cahiers that now won't accept them. But, according to the same source: "Existing €500 banknotes continue to be legal tender, so you can still use them as a means of payment and store of value (i.e. spend and save them). Similarly, banks, bureaux de change and other commercial parties can keep recirculating the existing €500 notes."

As only €500 notes were discontinued, you shouldn't run into the same trouble with a €100 note.

Comment: Note that the term "legal tender" only applies to debt payments (when you are *tendered* to the payment). Private businesses are free not to accept paper money at all.

Comment: A taxi driver probably couldn't refuse to take a €100 bill for a €100 ride unless indicated before the ride started.

Answer (score 2):

That depends where you are. The countries of Europe vary in wealth a lot.

I live in Germany and even within the country there are huge differences. Usually the 500€ bill is not accepted (and it is also not printed anymore).

But in my home town Frankfurt, we have an ATM in the inner city (Zeil, direction Goethe-Straße) which only gives out 500€-Bills. And shops in the area to go along with that.

You will also have no issue to pay with a 100€-Bill in any shop in the city.
I have even used 200€-Bills in the Supermarket.

In more remote places smaller denominations will be preferred. But you will always be able to use a 100€.

In other country's of the Euro-Zone I have made different experiences.

Short answer: It very much depends on the country, city and kind of shop you want to spend it in.

Comment: I would also add that the countries of Europe vary wildly in how cash friendly they are.  I was unable to pay my €50 hairdresser bill by card in Germany last week; I wouldn't be surprised to find a French hairdresser that would decline to accept cash.

Comment: Huh.  I live near Frankfurt am Main and I've never even *seen* a €100 bill, let alone anything larger than that.  Is that some novelty ATMs for people making their living in *Bahnhofsviertel* and therefore keen on large cash transactions? :)

Comment: Germany and the Netherlands do not differ much, or any, in wealth, but I have never handled a €100 bill. Most ATM here give 10, 20 and 50 notes.

Comment: @Willeke I once got one abroad and getting rid of it was a major pain (in Amsterdam, perhaps it's better near the German border).

Comment: @gerrit it is a Sparkasse ATM near Goethe-Straße,

Comment: What does that has to do with wealth?

Comment: A richer country will be more accepting to larger bills. And of course also the prices will be higher, so larger denominations are also required.

Answer (score 2):

[italy](/questions/tagged/italy)

The image below comes from the statistics page of the Bank of Italy, and shows the amount of bills (thousands of units) emitted by the bank, divided by type ("taglio": 5, 10, 20, 50, 100, 500 euro) and by year.

As you can see, the lion's share goes to 50 euro bills, but 100 aren't by any means uncommon.

There's a maximum amount for cash payments - currently it's 5.000 euros, with a low of 1.000 euros for the first months of 2022. These amounts are usually paid with larger denomination bills.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[spain](/questions/tagged/spain)

In Spain ATMs don't distribute 100€ notes or higher. Only 50, 20, 10 and 5€ notes. They can, however, be acquired at the bank's office.

It's common for stores, especially smaller ones, to have signs saying they don't accept notes above 50€.

So no, 100€ notes and higher are extremely rare in Spain. You just won't see them. If you do, make a wish.

Answer (score 1):

[italy](/questions/tagged/italy)

100€ bill is uncommon but not seen as shady. The acceptance depends upon the availability of change and the possibility of fraud: do not even try to pay a newspaper with it, but 80€ at the supermarket is fine; moreover, if the shop has a some kind of autenticity check device, they more likely will accept it. Same goes for the 200€ bill.

As for 500€ bills, they are definitely uncommon and not used for everyday payments.